# Huffman in JPEG decoding: what are symbols, codes and length

Tags: c++, jpeg, decoding, huffman-code

I'm following Daniel Harding's youtube playlist "Everything you need to know about JPEG" to understand how the JPEG File Format is defined.

In the decoding process, the code looks something like this:

```
length = getNextSymbol()
...
coefficient = readBits(length)
mcu[0] = coefficient
```

and the getNextSymbol function does smth like this:

```
currentCode = 0;
for i < 16:
    currentCode = (currentCode << 1) | readNextBit()
    for each huffman_code with length i:
        if currentCode == huffman_code:
            return huffman_symbols[huffman_code]
```

the complete code is hosted on github:
https://github.com/dannye/jed/blob/master/src/decoder.cpp

So we're first getting the symbol which should be the value that we want to parse. But after that we read the length of this symbol.
Is the huffman table only storing how many bits to read and not the "real" value. **But in AC decoding we store the symbol directly into our mcu values!**

What I understood:

- huffman code = the bit sequence or path to the symbol
- huffman symbol = the value we want to encode with this code

Question:
Why are we reading the symbol and then converting the symbol into a length, reading this length and storing the value that we read. But in AC we store the symbol without reading the bit.

What am I missing here?
Thanks for helping, its really tough to understand for me!

Comment: presumably the coefficients are too random to benefit from huffman coding so its more efficient to store a huff coded length followed by a value (most coefficients will be small values)

Comment: I think the actual problem here is that you're trying to understand the JPEG file format from a video. I recommend a book about this topic. JPEG contains a run length encoding. Perhaps the `lengrh` is used for this step.

Comment: I found the solution! I didn't see the next lines and the ac indeed is written in the same way. Still it seems strange to me to only store length of the values. @ThomasSablik I am reading the book "Compressed Image File Formats: JPEG, PNG, GIF, XBM, BMP".

Answer (score 3):

A DC component is represented by a Huffman coded bit count, followed by that number of bits interpreted as a signed integer. That integer is added to the DC coefficient of the last block to get the DC coefficient of this block. (For the first block, the "previous" DC coefficient is taken to be zero.)

An AC component is represented by Huffman coded run length/bit count, followed by that number of bits interpreted as a signed integer. The run length is in the high four bits of the decoded symbol, and the bit count is in the low four bits. Each such component results in a sequence of zero coefficients whose length is the run length, followed by a coefficient whose signed value is the bits that followed the code.

In both cases some number of bits are fetched after the Huffman code to get a coefficient value. So I don't know what you mean by "But in AC decoding we store the symbol directly into our mcu values!"

Comment: Thanks! This helped. I didnt See the read of the next byte. AS usual the Problem was myself ;)